# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Tags: mysql, mysqli, this

Estoy trabajando en hacer un respaldo a la base de datos y tengo un código funcional sin embargo debe ser actualizado a mysqli.

Intenté esto para actualizar esta sección del código:

```
    public function backup() {
    

        $this->Connect();

        // Begin new backup of MySql
        $tables = mysqli_query($this->Connect(), 'SHOW TABLES' );

        $sql_file  = "# WordPress : buffernow.com MySQL database backup\n";
        $sql_file .= "#\n";
        $sql_file .= "# Generated: " . date( 'l j. F Y H:i T' ) . "\n";
        $sql_file .= "# Hostname: " . $this->host . "\n";
        $sql_file .= "# Database: " . $this->sql_backquote( $this->database ) . "\n";
        $sql_file .= "# --------------------------------------------------------\n";

        for ( $i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows( $tables ); $i++ ) {

            $curr_table = mysqli_tablename( $tables, $i );

            // Create the SQL statements
            $sql_file .= "# --------------------------------------------------------\n";
            $sql_file .= "# Table: " . $this->sql_backquote( $curr_table ) . "\n";
            $sql_file .= "# --------------------------------------------------------\n";

            $this->make_sql( $sql_file, $curr_table );

        }
    return $this->database_dump_filename;

    }
```

Pero me da este error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Esta es la conexión

```
public function __construct( $dbhost,$database,$dbUser ,$dbPass, $path="") {
        @ini_set( 'memory_limit', '32M' );
        @set_time_limit( 0 );       
        
        $this->host = $dbhost;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->user = $dbUser;
        $this->pass = $dbPass ;
        $this->file_path = ($path) ? $path : dirname(__FILE__) ;
        
    }
    
    private function Connect() {
         mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->database) or die(mysqli_error());
        
    }
```

Aiuda

Comment: Hola Antony, por si no queda claro el porque del error, te diría que revises tu método `Connect()`, ya que o no hace un `return` de la conexión o algo más esta fallando.

Comment: ¿Por qué llamas dos veces `$this->Connect()`? ¿Conectarse dos veces? ¿No es suficiente con una conexión?.

Comment: Aparte de que estás llamando dos veces a `$this->Connect()` sin necesidad, como bien señala @Sal, parece que `Connect()` te está devolviendo `null`. Cuando plantees una pregunta pon todo el código implicado. En este caso es fundamental ver lo que ocurre en el método `Connect()`. Sea como sea, esta pregunta ya ha sido planteada y resuelta anteriormente, fíjate en la pregunta referida más arriba.

Comment: Ya había leído la publicación a la que hacen referencia pero no supe como adaptarlo a la forma en la que está hecha el código que tengo.

Comment: @Sal probé de esa manera porque leí en el manual de php que el mysqli_query necesita el parámetro de conexión, aunque la verdad no eh visto ejemplos usando $this por ello no se como adaptarlo

Comment: @A.Cedano, creo que ya se puede reabrir esta pregunta. Si bien esta relacionada con la marcada como duplicada, el OP esta pidiendo ayuda con la modificación de su código.

Comment: @Marcos el problema, ahora que ha mostrado el código de la función, es que falta un `return`, no hay más misterio. Así debería funcionar: **`private function Connect() { return mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->database);}`** Yo quitaría el `die()`, porque rompería el flujo por ejemplo en escenarios donde se espera como respuesta un JSON o un XML, y evaluaría el estado de la conexión allí donde es llamada, para escribir un código siempre adaptado al contexto donde se usa.

Comment: @A.Cedano, precisamente por eso es que considero que deberia reabrirse la pregunta. Creo que amerita una respuesta con código. PD: Se podría guardar la conexión para que al llamar `connect` no cree otra nueva.

Comment: Listo @Marcos he otorgado mi voto de reapertura.